# Is it normal for mysql to be slow when connecting to a remote host?

Tags: mysql, performance, host

Is it normal for mysql to be slow when connecting to a remote host or should it have the same performance as connecting to a local host?

I noticed a small performance difference, when I tried to connect to a remote host, so I'm wondering if that's normal?

Comment: Define "slow". Yes, connecting to a remote host can be a bit slower than connecting locally. Whether or not you will see any noticeable impact in real use depends on a lot of things (what are you doing? how much data are you transferring? are you using a connection pool? ...)

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that the remote machine is equal in terms of processing power as your local machine, then the primary difference in speed should be network latency - the round trip time for a network traffic.  If you are sending huge amounts of data (e.g., reading or writing large BLOBs), then the network bandwidth can come into play as well and "slow" things down.  But in general, the round trip cost is often the biggest factor.  If you are executing a large number of "small" queries, this cost difference can be fairly significant when comparing a local connection to a remote connection.

Out of curiosity, I just now ran a test that I had already built that simply runs a bunch of update queries.  This is not using MySQL but another client/server DBMS.  Thus the results would likely be different, but the idea is the same and I would imagine the relative differences would not be significantly different.

```
Local host (using IPC comm):  5.3 seconds
Remote host (UDP comm):  20.2 seconds
```

This involved about 50,000 operations.  The remote host was 2 hops away on the LAN with (if I measured it correctly) a round trip latency of approximately 0.25 ms for a packet with a 1 byte payload.

Answer (score 4):

It depends entirely on the network connection between the program and the MySQL database server.  A slow network will make the database appear slow.

I'd expect a "small performance difference" (as you described it) to be normal for a remote connection.

Comment: Depends on how "remote" this is. For local networks, it will be negligible; for connecting to a server halfway across the world, it will be slow as molasses.

Comment: question: it takes about 20 seconds to log in on my network database. but the queries are fast. would that be normal?

Answer (score 1):

By default the MySQL server will perform a reverse DNS lookup the first time a client connects to it. It then stores this in its cache. This can potentially give a performance hit depending on the speed of the reverse DNS resolution.

Answer (score 0):

It can depend on how many MySQL queries you're doing:  [Slow MySQL Remote Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558502/slow-mysql-remote-connection)

You can optimize your code by converting many small queries into larger ones.